# Prove that $S^{-1}M\otimes_{S^{-1}R} S^{-1}N=S^{-1}M\otimes_R S^{-1}N$

Tags: commutative-algebra, modules, tensor-products, localization

**Problem:** Let $R$ be a commutative ring, $S\subset R$ multiplicative and $M,N$ $R$-modules. Show that
$$S^{-1}M \otimes_R N=S^{-1}M\otimes_{S^{-1}R} S^{-1}N=S^{-1}M\otimes_R S^{-1}N,$$
where $S^{-1}(\cdot)$ is the localization.

**My attempt:** Using the cancellation law, and the fact that the functors $S^{-1}(\cdot)$ and $S^{-1}R\otimes_R\cdot$ are isomorphic, I get
\begin{align*}
S^{-1}M \otimes_R N &= S^{-1}M\otimes_{S^{-1}R}(S^{-1}R\otimes_R N)\\
&= S^{-1}M\otimes_{S^{-1}R}S^{-1}N
\end{align*}

Now, how would I go around to prove the second isomorphism? Many thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you show all three objects enjoy the same universal property?

Comment: Do you mean equality or isomorphism? Furthermore, isomorphic as what? Answering this itself might be helpful.

Comment: I mean isomorphism. I will change that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

More generally, if $R \to T$ is an [epimorphism](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/epimorphism) in the category of commutative rings (for example, every localization $R \to S^{-1} R$) and $M,N$ are two $T$-modules, then the canonical map of $R$-modules
$$M \otimes_R N \to M \otimes_T N$$
is an isomorphism. Since both sides are cocontinuous functors in $M$ and $N$, and $M,N$ are colimits of copies of $T$, it suffices to prove that the canonical map
$$T \otimes_R T \to T$$
is an isomorphism. But this is one of the characterizations of an epimorphism $f : X \to Y$ in a category, namely that the codiagonal $Y \sqcup_X Y \to Y$ is an isomorphism.

Of course, you can also fiddle around with elements to prove the result for localizations. You only need to argue that a $R$-bilinear map $\beta$ between $S^{-1} R$-modules is also $S^{-1} R$-bilinear (and conversely, but the converse is trivial). But $\beta(s^{-1} x,y) = s^{-1} \beta(x,y)$ is equivalent to $s \beta(s^{-1} x,y) = \beta(x,y)$, and the left side is, in fact, equal to $\beta(s s^{-1} x,y)=\beta(x,y)$.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Why is it enough to argue that an $R$-bilinear map between $S^{-1}R$-modules is $S^{-1}R$-bilinear and vice versa?

Comment: Remember that tensor products are defined by a universal property. Every statement about tensor products is actually a statement about bilinear maps.

Comment: Specifically, to produce a map $M \otimes_{S^{-1} R} N \to M \otimes_R N$, you need to argue that the universal $R$-bilinear map $M \times N \to M \otimes_R N$ is actually $S^{-1} R$-bilinear.

Comment: To see if I understood. I need to consider a $R$-bilinear map $\beta:S^{-1}M\times S^{-1}P$, and prove it is $S^{-1}R$-bilinear. Fix $x/s\in S^{-1}M$ and $y/t\in S^{-1}N$, then I need to show
$$\beta(x'/s'+x''/s'',y/t)=\beta(x'/s',y/t)+\beta(x''/s'',y/t)$$
$$\beta(x/s, y'/t'+y''/t'')=\beta(x/s,y'/t)+\beta(x/s,y''/t'')$$
$$\beta(r/u\cdot x/s,y/t)=\beta(x/s, r/u\cdot y/t)$$
where $r/u\in s^{-1}R$. Right? How would I accomplish the first one, for example?